# Can ViewModel store data?

Tags: c#, mvvm

Short question. Is it acceptable in MVVM pattern to create list in viewmodel where user input will be storage and later saved in database?

I'm creating app where user have to describe device appearance. User enters description in textbox and is added to listbox. Later on it will be saved in database. ListBox is databinded to

```
ObservableCollection<string>
```

Its seems natural to me to put ObservableCollection in ViewModel but for what i know all data should be in Model.

Where should I put my list to make it match the MVVM pattern?

Comment: I don't see an issue with this personally, however there will always be at least one hardliner that will tell you otherwise. MVVM is laid out slightly different by different sources, so I would just do what feels correct to you and not waste too much time on getting the pattern right 100%.

Comment: AFAIK there should be no problems with bound ObservableCollections held in the ViewModel at runtime.

Comment: Question is primarily opinion based. That said, I routinely write WPF code where the view model is the only model. It seems wasteful to me to wrap a separate model data structure in a view model data structure that just repeats all of the implementation for the sake of the UI. I have even used such view model-based code in non-WPF apps; i.e. used the same view model-based DLL as a library for both a WPF app and a non-WPF app. Patterns are there to serve you, not the other way around.

Comment: "all data should be in Model" is true but that's not really a contradiction. The data is part of the View in an (implied) session until it's saved.